# Flutter MouseRegion onExit not working near edge of browser

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, if I have a MouseRegion on a widget that's right up against the edge of the browser, mousing off the widget outside of the browser will not cause an onExit to fire. This works in other frameworks. Is there a work around?

In the screenshot below, the mouse exit should clear the green background color. It works when the mouse cursor is within the browser client.

[image: MouseRegion onExit example]

Answer (score -1):

Its not working because you are not "exiting" the MouseRegion, you are exiting the browser but you have to touch something inside the area the mouseRegion is listening to, for it to know you exited it.

If you want a "work around" you can add a small container to the lefy of the museRegion with the same height and color, so when you exit from that side, you the app can recognize the action.

But as far as i've used it, that is how it works.